# Return specific urls only in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape urls from a website. At the moment it returns all the urls, but I want it to return only urls that contain the word 'download'. How can I do this?

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy

DOMAIN = 'somedomain.com'
URL = 'http://' +str(DOMAIN) 

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            print url
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

EDIT:

I implemented the suggestions below. It still throws some errors but at least this returns only the links containing download.

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


DOMAIN = 'somedomain.com'
URL = 'http://' +str(DOMAIN) 

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

# First parse returns all the links of the website and feeds them to parse2 

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse2)

# Second parse selects only the links that contains download

    def parse2(self, response):
        le = LinkExtractor(allow=("download"))
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
                yield Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse2)
                print link.url
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a more pythonic and clean solution, would be to use `LinkExtractor`:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

...

le = LinkExtractor(deny="download")
for link in le.extract_links(response):
    yield Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you, I made it work but in this way the code denies each link with 'download', so that's at least half way, but how can I do it the other way around?

Comment: check [LinkExtractor documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html), it also offers the `allow` attribute, so you can create another LinkExtractor instance with that.

Comment: Just tried it, I get the same warning as with dot.Py's answer: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong, the initial url does not have direct links to the pages I wanted to go to. By not allowing any other urls except the one I was looking for I ended up blocking the path. So I misunderstood it as an error because no results were displayed. By crawling in two steps it worked. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: I have one more related question; whenever a link doesn't contain the word download, the script throws up an attribute error (but does continue): 

    File "/Users/.../subscript2.py", line 29, in parse2 
    ...File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 91, in text
    raise AttributeError("Response content isn't text")

Is this how it is supposed to work, or should I add a line or parameter that deals with the return values that are not allowed?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to check if a substring is present in a string.

**Example:**

```
string = 'this is a simple string'

'simple' in string
True

'zimple' in string
False
```

---

So, you just have to add an `if` statement like:

`if 'download' in url:`

After the line:

`for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():`

**I.e.:**

```
for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
    if 'download' in url:
        if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
            url = URL + url 
        print url
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

So the code will only check if link starts with `http://` if the condition `'download' in url` returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried something like this myself. When I do it this way scrapy throws an error and tells me to use one of its selectors, css or xpath instead...

Comment: Solved, it does work but my crawler was blocking its own crawling path.